# PHPDoc return type for trait function

Tags: php-7, phpdoc, php-7.2

I have functions like the following in my code that return the object (for chaining):

```
    /**
     * Set properties
     *
     * @param $name
     * @param $value
     *
     * @return \Boka10\Page\MenuItemConfig
     */
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {

        $this->$name = $value;

        return $this;
    }
```

I want to move this function into a trait because, well, basically it is reused all the time.

My problem is, that the `return $this` line makes problems in the documentation section. In my PHPDoc it says (in this example) `@return \Boka10\Page\MenuItemConfig`.

How do I create a "global" trait method whose return documentation contains the correct typecast? Is it possible to do that or should I just add the `__set` function to each class?

I am not sure if I can explain what problem I am having here ;) What exactly would be the content of the `@return` tag in a globally used trait if all of these objects return their own instance?

Comment: Have you figured out a solution? Returning `self` and other constructs I know about all have issues.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I found a psalm specific way and added an answer about it. I did not test with other tools though...

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's a bit of mess, traits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging and "hacking" I checked out the tests in Psalm and found, that the following seems to be the best method to comment these cases:

```php
/**
 * @method string somefunction($name, $value)
 * @property string $name
 */
class ImplementTrait {

    use MagicTrait;

}
```

The properties and methods are documented on the implementing class.

Note: I am using Psalm to check the code quality and this is psalms accepted way:

- [Psalm Tests for __call annotations](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/blob/master/tests/MagicMethodAnnotationTest.php)
- [Psalm tests for __get/__set annotations](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/blob/master/tests/MagicPropertyTest.php)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following approach to add auto-completion in PHPStorm when using classes that implement some interfaces.

I create an interface with a skeleton of all target Trait public methods and extend it.

Example:

```
Trait MySimpleTrait {
    /** 
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function someMethod($someArg){
        return doSomethingWithSomeArg($someArg);
    }
}

Interface MySimpleTraitInterface {
    /**
     *
     * This method do some thing with <var>$someArg</>
     *
     * @param mixed $someArg
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function someMethod($someArg);
}

interface MySimpleServiceInterface extends MySimpleTraitInterface
{
}

class MySimpleService implements MySimpleServiceInterface
{
    use MySimpleTrait;
}
```

PHPStorm showing autocomplete for method defined in Trait:

[image: PHPStorm showing autocomplete for method defined in Trait]

PHPStorm showing phpDoc for method defined in Trait:

[image: PHPStorm showing phpDoc for method defined in Trait]

Seems absurd in 2022, but I have a lot of projects with PHP 5.6 and the syntax is supposed to be compatible (i.e., no typehint in non-scalar args or return functions).